# ProxyServlet stop working after migration from jetty 8 to jetty 9

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jetty

I have an eclipse plugin which uses jetty server with ProxyServlet. Basically, the implementation is the following:

```
    ServletHolder proxyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new SubClassOfProxyServlet()); 
    proxyServletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
    ServletHandler proxyServletHandler = new ServletHandler();
    proxyServletHandler.addServletWithMapping(proxyServletHolder, "/mapping/url");
```

After that I add proxy handler to the handler list and set this list to the server:

```
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {
            . // Other Handlers
            .
            proxyServletHandler,
            .
            .
            .
            new DefaultHandler()
        });
    server.setHandler(handlers);
```

Everything worked like a charm against **jetty 8** but after migration to **jetty 9** I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No server executor for proxy
    at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet.createHttpClient(ProxyServlet.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:123)
    ... 24 more`

Has the mechanism of working with ProxyServer changed? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your `SubClassOfProxyServlet` class to include the various configurations that are now being passed from the `Server` to the Proxy which are then in turn used by the internal `HttpClient`

The particular error means you are not passing along the Executor properly.

You have 2 choices for the Executor specific piece (there might be more things for you to configure after this is addressed)

1. Set the init-parameter `maxThreads` to a valid integer value.
2. or Create an Executor, and set it in the servlet context attributes at `ServletContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor", myExecutor)` on application deployment / startup.  - You could probably do this as well in your `SubClassOfProxyServlet.init(ServletConfig config)` method.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example? It's extremely difficult to find one

Comment: Tough to do, as most people don't subclass ProxyServlet, but just use it as-is.  Also, some long term notes, ProxyServlet is slowly being deprecated and replaced with [AsyncProxyServlet](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncProxyServlet.java) (a near complete rewrite for proper Async I/O use)

Comment: Thanks for help. Will try to handle it somehow ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working via the `maxThreads` method mentioned above, setting it on creation. Applying this to the original example would result in this:

```
ServletHolder proxyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new SubClassOfProxyServlet()); 
proxyServletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
proxyServletHolder.setInitParameter("maxThreads", "2");
ServletHandler proxyServletHandler = new ServletHandler();
proxyServletHandler.addServletWithMapping(proxyServletHolder, "/mapping/url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can add a servlet to a list of handlers:

```
    private void addWebApp(String contextPath, String resourceBase, Server server) {

        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        // webAppContext.setDescriptor(webapp + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webAppContext.setResourceBase(resourceBase);
        webAppContext.setContextPath(contextPath);
        webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        webAppContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"index.html"});
        webAppContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");
        webAppContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");

        final ServletHolder servletHolder =new ServletHolder();
        servletHolder.setAsyncSupported(ContentBasedProxyServlet.class);
        servletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);

        webAppContext.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

        HandlerList handlers = (HandlerList) server.getHandler();
        handlers.addHandler(webAppContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can put `maxThreads` to `web.xml` as well:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>example.MyProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```